# Setting up Kie WB 6.3.0.CR2 and Execution Server 6.3.0.CR2 cant find where to connect?

Tags: drools, kie-workbench, kie-wb

I have just installed the following 2 wars onto a WildFly 9.0.1 server:

http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.CR2/kie-drools-wb-distribution-6.3.0.CR2.zip
http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.CR2/kie-server-distribution-6.3.0.CR2.zip

I setup the WB and Execution server user profiles and it all looks good and tested the execution server and got the following response:

```
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="Kie Server info">

<kie-server-info>

<capabilities>BPM</capabilities>
<capabilities>KieServer</capabilities>
<capabilities>BRM</capabilities>
<location>
http://localhost:8230/kie-server/services/rest/server
</location>
<name>KieServer@/kie-server-6.3.0.CR2-ee7</name>
<id>a12dda17-70b8-3f50-8999-37e3d030dedd</id>
<version>6.3.0.CR2</version>
</kie-server-info>
</response>
```

When I go to Deploy -> Rule Deployments and select the 'Register' option from the top right I was excepting to be able to enter the endpoint information etc as I was able to in 6.2.0. However I see this

[image]

This merely asks for the Identifier and the Name but when i put the endpoint in the identifier field it doesn't seem to work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Also I have noticed other users have high level menu items like 'Servers', 'Dashboards' etc and I cant see any of these. How do I set them up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not put endpoint in the identifier, you actually put the values from XMl you posted:

```
<name>KieServer@/kie-server-6.3.0.CR2-ee7</name>
<id>a12dda17-70b8-3f50-8999-37e3d030dedd</id>
<version>6.3.0.CR2</version>
```

Kie server registers itself on workbench server. To do that you put this on java_opts in kie execution server configuration file /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:8080/drools-wb/rest/controller -Dorg.kie.server.id=first-kie-server -Dorg.kie.server.controller.user=ks-user -Dorg.kie.server.controller.pwd=ks-user -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8180/kie-server/services/rest/server"
```

You can see details about properties here: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html/ch22.html#d0e21647

In short, endpoint is defined by org.kie.server.location (if you want to set it on specific server/port where your KIE execution server is, user/pass for Workbench to post these values via controller REST and the location of controller (workbench) server in org.kie.server.controller. I also set the kie execution server ID so that it is readable instead of autogenerated ("a12dda17-70b8-3f50-8999-37e3d030dedd" in your case).

When you start kie execution server with these parameters, you should see green icon beside this server in Deploy->Rule deployments.